# Show grid elements automatically below each other

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, css

See i am working on this page, first is for women, second is for men :

```
http://www.woolovers.com/cashmere-merino/womens/classic-ladies-crew-cardigan.aspx
http://www.woolovers.com/lambswool/unisex/lambswool-slipover-vest.aspx
```

As you can see the sizes at the top of the swatch color grid vary. For men ( S M L XL XXL ) and for women ( S M L XL )

[image: See this grid on that page]

The html for that grid in the aspx file is :

```
<div class="SwatchGrid sw-color">
    <div class="sw-item">
        <asp:HyperLink ID="lnkColourURL" runat="server">
            <asp:Image ID="imgSwatch" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="20px" BorderWidth="0" />
        </asp:HyperLink><span><a id="hrfColourLink" runat="server" class="SwatchColourLabel ordr_grid">
            <asp:Literal ID="lblColour" runat="server"></asp:Literal></a></span></div>
    <div class="sw-sizes-av">
        <div id="tdXs" runat="server" visible="false">
            <span id="spXS" runat="server" visible="false">
                <img id="imgXSarge<%=mstrXSID%>" src="<%=mstrXSURL%>" onclick="ImageClicked('imgXSarge',<%=mstrXSID%>,'<%=mstrXSMsg%>',<%=onXSWait %>)"
                    onmouseover="ImageOver(<%=mstrStyleID%>,<%=mstrXSSwatchID%>,<%=mstrColWay %>,'<%=ImagePath %>','<%=strAlt %>')"
                    onmouseout="ImageOut(<%=mstrColWay %>)" alt="<%=mstrXSTitle%>" title="<%=mstrXSTitle%>"
                    class="CurPointer" /></span>
        </div>
        <div id="tdS" runat="server" visible="false">
            <span id="spS" runat="server" visible="false">
                <img id="imgSmall<%=mstrSID%>" src="<%=mstrSURL%>" onclick="ImageClicked('imgSmall',<%=mstrSID%>,'<%=mstrSMsg%>',<%=onSWait %>)"
                    onmouseover="ImageOver(<%=mstrStyleID%>,<%=mstrSSwatchID%>,<%=mstrColWay %>,'<%=ImagePath %>','<%=strAlt %>')"
                    onmouseout="ImageOut(<%=mstrColWay %>)" alt="<%=mstrSTitle%>" title="<%=mstrSTitle%>"
                    class="CurPointer" /></span>
        </div>
        <div id="tdM" runat="server" visible="false">
            <span id="spM" runat="server" visible="false">
                <img id="imgMedium<%=mstrMID%>" src="<%=mstrMURL%>" onclick="ImageClicked('imgMedium',<%=mstrMID%>,'<%=mstrMMsg%>',<%=onMWait %>)"
                    onmouseover="ImageOver(<%=mstrStyleID%>,<%=mstrMSwatchID%>,<%=mstrColWay %>,'<%=ImagePath %>','<%=strAlt %>')"
                    onmouseout="ImageOut(<%=mstrColWay %>)" alt="<%=mstrMTitle%>" title="<%=mstrMTitle%>"
                    class="CurPointer" /></span>
        </div>
        <div id="tdL" runat="server" visible="false">
            <span id="spL" runat="server" visible="false">
                <img id="imgLarge<%=mstrLID%>" src="<%=mstrLURL%>" onclick="ImageClicked('imgLarge',<%=mstrLID%>,'<%=mstrLMsg%>',<%=onLWait %>)"
                    onmouseover="ImageOver(<%=mstrStyleID%>,<%=mstrLSwatchID%>,<%=mstrColWay %>,'<%=ImagePath %>','<%=strAlt %>')"
                    onmouseout="ImageOut(<%=mstrColWay %>)" alt="<%=mstrLTitle%>" title="<%=mstrLTitle%>"
                    class="CurPointer" /></span>
        </div>
        <div id="tdXL" runat="server" visible="false">
            <span id="spXL" runat="server" visible="false">
                <img id="imgXLarge<%=mstrXLID%>" src="<%=mstrXLURL%>" onclick="ImageClicked('imgXLarge',<%=mstrXLID%>,'<%=mstrXLMsg%>',<%=onXLWait %>)"
                    onmouseover="ImageOver(<%=mstrStyleID%>,<%=mstrXLSwatchID%>,<%=mstrColWay %>,'<%=ImagePath %>','<%=strAlt %>')"
                    onmouseout="ImageOut(<%=mstrColWay %>)" alt="<%=mstrXLTitle%>" title="<%=mstrXLTitle%>"
                    class="CurPointer" /></span>
        </div>
        <div id="tdXXXL" runat="server" visible="false">
            <span id="spXXXL" runat="server" visible="false">
                <img id="imgXXXLarge<%=mstrXXXLID%>" src="<%=mstrXXXLURL%>" onclick="ImageClicked('imgXXXLarge',<%=mstrXXXLID%>,'<%=mstrXXXLMsg%>',<%=onXXXLWait %>)"
                    onmouseover="ImageOver(<%=mstrStyleID%>,<%=mstrXXXLSwatchID%>,<%=mstrColWay %>,'<%=ImagePath %>','<%=strAlt %>')"
                    onmouseout="ImageOut(<%=mstrColWay %>)" alt="<%=mstrXXXLTitle%>" title="<%=mstrXXXLTitle%>"
                    class="CurPointer" /></span></div>
        <div id="tdXXL" runat="server" visible="false">
            <span id="spXXL" runat="server" visible="false">
                <img id="imgXXLarge<%=mstrXXLID%>" src="<%=mstrXXLURL%>" onclick="ImageClicked('imgXXLarge',<%=mstrXXLID%>,'<%=mstrXXLMsg%>',<%=onXXLWait %>)"
                    onmouseover="ImageOver(<%=mstrStyleID%>,<%=mstrXXLSwatchID%>,<%=mstrColWay %>,'<%=ImagePath %>','<%=strAlt %>')"
                    onmouseout="ImageOut(<%=mstrColWay %>)" alt="<%=mstrXXLTitle%>" title="<%=mstrXXLTitle%>"
                    class="CurPointer" /></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cls">
    </div>
</div>
<%}
  else
  { %>
<%--<div class="sw-item1">&nbsp;</div>--%>
<div class="sw-sizes">
    <div id="tdHXS" runat="server" visible="false">
        <span id="spHXS" runat="server" visible="false" >
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:common,Size_XS%>"></asp:Literal></span></div>
    <div id="tdHS" runat="server" visible="false">
        <span id="spHS" runat="server" visible="false" >
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:common,Size_S%>"></asp:Literal></span></div>
    <div id="tdHM" runat="server" visible="false">
        <span id="spHM" runat="server" visible="false" >
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal3" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:common,Size_M%>"></asp:Literal></span></div>
    <div id="tdHL" runat="server" visible="false">
        <span id="spHL" runat="server" visible="false" >
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal4" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:common,Size_L%>"></asp:Literal></span></div>
    <div id="tdHXL" runat="server"  visible="false">
        <span id="spHXL" runat="server" visible="false" >
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal5" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:common,Size_XL%>"></asp:Literal></span></div>
    <div id="tdHXXXL" runat="server" visible="false">
        <span id="spHXXXL" runat="server" visible="false">
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal7" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:common,Size_XXXL%>"></asp:Literal></span></div>
    <div id="tdHXXL" runat="server" visible="false"> 
        <span id="spHXXL" runat="server" visible="false">
            <asp:Literal ID="Literal6" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:common,Size_XXL%>"></asp:Literal></span></div>
</div>
<% } %>
```

Now the issue is, that there can be random sizes available on a product ( from small (S) to Triple XL (XXXL) ). In this case there are 4 ( S/M/L/XL ). Now if there is no M size on the black color, the S size's image for BLACK color moves to the right ( because of .sw-sizes-av is having width:auto ). How to keep that and any other image into its place without making this into a table layout? I hope you get what i am trying to say here.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, remove

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SwatchGrid1_swl11_tdXXXL">
        </div>
```

and

```
<div id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_SwatchGrid1_swl11_tdXs">   
    </div>
```

if it is not needed. I see that the header only has S,M,L,XL,XXL but there are 7 different `<div>`. XS,S,M,L,XL,XXL,XXXL. Don't use the divs if you do not have a corresponding header.

Secondly, all divs which may/may not have the available sizes should have a class..Let us make that class `content-size`.

You'd add the following css to this class

```
.content-size{
width:20px; /* because your span has 2px margin */
height:18px;
}
```

Attaching the screenshot of the relevant html

[image]

Comment: The image would be inside this span tag? The sizes which are not available completely are set to visible=false in aspx, just fyi.

Comment: No. If a size is not available, there'd be no image tag. And combine that with the css.

To elaborate.

you still have 4 span tags all of which have the above css. But only 1 of them will not have an <img> tag.

Comment: @Harmeet what do you set visible=false to ?

Comment: The div and span tag  in which the image is coming.

Comment: @Harmeet I saw the code in Chrome browser and I see that the span is not there but the div tag is...There are also some extra div tags..Why is that the case? I was looking at the second link you attached.

Comment: I'm understanding your problem better now. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Example : Product1 is in S/M/L/XL so, only the divs with that image will be displayed rest will be visible=false. Product2 is in S M L XL XXL so, only the divs with that image will be displayed rest will be visible=false. Make sense ?

Comment: @Harmeet Yes, that did make sense. However, i notice a few problems and added those in my edited answer

Comment: Removing those div will create an issue for those products which do have that particular size. This is all coming dynamically so removing anything is not an option unless there is a replacement for that particular process/code. For instance removing the XXXL div will remove it completely and the products which do have XXXL in them also wont show that option.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22167/discussion-between-aditya-saxena-and-harmeet)

Comment: Even if a product were to have XXXL size, how will it show ? You have no XXXL header.